# PHP - Generate a random 5 digit number with a exception from an array

Tags: arrays, exception, random, numbers, generator

I want to generate a random 5 digit number for a file name, with exception. 
If PHP will generate for example the number 65, I want to be set 00065 (only 5 digit).
I have a array who contains a exception for the generator:
 
`$uploaded_files= array(00178, 49856, 32183, 02004, 01585);`
In the array are the file names who already exists, and the number generator is very important to omit them, to avoid possible errors.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider not to [re-invent the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), especially when the wheel is available in your language in [one way](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php) or [another](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php#99425). That being said:

```
/**
 * Get random number outside an exception list
 *
 * @param array $exception Exception list
 */
function getRandom($exception=array('00001', '00002', '00003', '00004', '00005')) {
    $rand=str_pad(mt_rand(0,10),5,0,STR_PAD_LEFT);
    if(in_array($rand,$exception))return getRandom($exception);
    return $rand;
}

var_dump(
    getRandom(),
    getRandom(),
    getRandom(),
    getRandom(),
    getRandom(),
    getRandom()
);
```

Do take note, this kind of implementation can really expensive on collisions really fast, especially if the exception list grows.

Comment: You made me smile with re-inventing the wheel, but you were right. Thank you for getRandom function!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//create a rand_value initially
while(in_array($rand_value, $uploaded_files) {
    $rand_value = rand(0, 99999);
    $rand_value = sprintf("%05s", $rand_value);
}
```

Comment: `<?php
$uploaded_files= array(01, 02, 03, 04, 05);

$rand_value = rand(0, 15);
$rand_value = sprintf("%02s", $rand_value);



if (in_array($rand_value,$uploaded_files)){
 echo 'Initial random-value: '.$rand_value.'<br>';
 echo 'Regenerated random-value: ';
 $rand_value = rand(0,15);
 $rand_value = sprintf("%02s", $rand_value);

}
else{
}

echo $rand_value;
?>`

If PHP in `in_array` will generate a rand and check who is in the array, what can I do? Please check the code.